# Android Studio basic quiz issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm trying to make a quiz in which I will have 4 buttons for possible answers. I want to check if the right button is pressed, if so I want to change the image for about 2 seconds and load the next question (which will be an image stored in an array) this will be in a for loop the length of the question array I believe?

I'm having some trouble with this, as I'm also unsure on how to load a new question and then it know which button needs to be pressed, for example. question 1 might need button 1 pressing but question 2 might be button 3 but I don't want to change activity.

creating the array and setting image view:

```
private  int[] ImageArr = new int[5];
private ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Question_ImgView);
```

filling array:

```
public void FillImage() {
ImageArr[0] = R.drawable.img1;
ImageArr[1] = R.drawable.img2;
ImageArr[2] = R.drawable.img3;
ImageArr[3] = R.drawable.img4;
ImageArr[4] = R.drawable.img5;}
```

this is then called in the "onCreate method" to fill array on launch

then i will have a questions method, this is where I want the before mentioned things to happen.

tldr; I need to know how to loop through an image array if correct button is pressed (correct button changes for each question), and change the text on the buttons, till all questions are answered.

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are your questions in the images ? and for your questions you will be having the options with the correct answer ?

Comment: My questions are the images yes, well, rather I have an image for each question and a caption below. The correct answer will be on the button, for example it could be like "what colour is this" and you press the button that says "blue" then because you got it correct it should load up the next image and answer set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing you should do is to create a `Question` class.

```
public class Question {
    @DrawableRes
    private int imageId;
    private String[] answers;
    private int correctAnswerIndex;

    public Question(int imageId, int correctAnswerIndex, String... answers) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    @DrawableRes
    public int getImageId() { return imageId; }
    public String[] getAnswers() { return answers; }
    public int getCorrectAnswerIndex() { return correctAnswerIndex; }
}
```

This class represents a question. It has

- an `imageId` field to store the image of the question
- an `answers` field to store all the possible answers that the user can choose
- a `correctAnswerIndex` to store the correct answer. This actually stores the index of the correct answer in the `answers` array. Say you have `{"blue", "red", "green", "yellow"}` as the `answers` array and the correct answer is `blue`, you will set the correct answer index to `0`.

Don't understand how to use it? Let's see an example.

At the moment, you have an array of image ids. You should change that to an array of `Question`s.

```
private Question[] questions = new Question[4];
```

And your `fillQuestion` method would be:

```
questions[0] = new Question(R.drawable.sweeper_is_handsome, 0, "True", "False", "Maybe", "I don't know");
questions[1] = new Question(R.drawable.no_one_can_beat_jon_skeet_in_reputation, 1, "True", "False", "Maybe", "I don't know");
// you get the idea.
```

As you can see, the answer to the first question is "True" (`correctAnswerIndex` = 0) and that to the second question is "False" (`correctAnswerIndex` = 1).

Now you have an array full of questions. How do you display it?

I think you can work out how to display the image yourself, so let's focus on how to get the buttons working.

I guess your buttons will be in an array, right? If it is isn't, then you're totally doing this wrong. Just add four buttons to an array, it's simple.

You can use the same on click handler for each button. It doesn't matter. In the on click listener, you have a `view` parameter like this right?

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
//                         ⬆︎
//                       here
}
```

If you are doing this right, `view` should be an item in your buttons array. You can use the `indexOf` method to get the index of the button in the array. If this index matches the `correctAnswerIndex` of the question, the user chose the correct answer!

But how do you know which question is displaying? You create a variable in your activity class called `questionIndex` to keep track of it! It should start at 0 and each time you display a new question, you increment it!

EDIT:

This is how your button on click handler would look like:

```
int pressedButtonIndex = btns.indexOf(view);
int correctAnswerIndex = questions[questionIndex].getCorrectAnswerIndex();

if (pressedButtonIndex == correctAnswerIndex) {
    // This means the user chose the correct answer
    if (questionIndex == 4) {
        // This is actually the last question! No need to display the next!
        return;
    }
    // load next question
    questionIndex++;

    someImageView.setImage(questions[questionIndex].getImageId());
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        btns[i].setText(questions[questionIndex].getAnswers()[i]);
    }
    // YAY! The next question is displayed.
} else {
    // User chose the wrong answer, do whatever you want here.
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this response it was actually really easy to follow (I'm not all that experienced) I'll give it a go later on and let you know how i get on!  :)

Comment: i made the buttons array:

    private Button btns[] = new Button[4];

    btns[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Ans1Btn);
    btns[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Ans2Btn);
    btns[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Ans3Btn);
    btns[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Ans4Btn);

But I am unsure of what you mean by having view in the array? and index of the button, how would i do that? thanks again :)

Comment: @flanelman In your on click listener, just do `btns.indexOf(view)` to get the index and compare this to the correct answer index of the current question.

Comment: also, the answers array and the correct answer index, how would this work if the answers were different for each question? as the answers array wouldn't be able to loop though different sets of 4 answers would they? Wouldn't that need an array for each question?

Comment: @flanelman Let's assume you have 4 questions. They are represented by a `Question[]`, right? Each time, you only display _one_ question, right? The question that you are displaying is the `questionIndex`. It should first start at  0 since you are displaying the first question first. You can get the currently displayed question by `questions[questionIndex]`. When you want to display the second question, do `questionIndex++;`. And then set the image view's image and the buttons' texts. **You do not need to use a for loop.**

Comment: @flanelman I've edited my answer to show you how you should write your on click handler. Just give it a try! Don't just keep saying "how can that work". Sometimes, nobody knows why, but it just works. :)

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick. @flanelman

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a general approach to your question, you can or may need to modify according to your needs,

You have an `Image Array` of questions and would like to know the `correct Button` was pressed or not, for that you will need the options and a `correct answer` to compare with the `Button clicked` to check if the correct `Button` was pressed or not,

and you do not need to loop through all the questions at once, what you can do is when the button is pressed, compare button text with the correct answer and if its correct then show the next question image, some code example for the same,

```
if(btnClicked.getText().toString().equals("Correct Answer")){
   questionPos++;
   imgView.setImageResource(questionPos);
   // Update all the buttons as per the new options
   btn1.setText(options1);
   // .... like wise update other buttons
}
```

see if this makes sense

**Edit**

as per you are asking how to know which button is clicked you can do something like this ...

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          if(btn1.getText().toString().equals("Correct Answer")){
             questionPos++;
             imgView.setImageResource(questionPos);
             // Update all the buttons as per the new options
             btn1.setText(options1);
          }
     }
});

// Similarly you can do for all other buttons
```

Comment: How does it know which button is clicked for "btnClicked"? also, how would this loop through all the answers? I don't really understand what options1 is, sorry.

Thanks for the response :)

Comment: you will set `onClickListener` for all buttons right ? then in all `onClick()` methods you can write the above code and regarding above option1, i amm thinking that you will be having some options for all the questions ?

Comment: yes i do. sorry, I'm unsure on what options are? I was planning on just having a set of answers wrote onto buttons per question with a different image displayed each time. 

thanks for the responses btw :)

Comment: Yes the options are the set of answers you have for each question